# ScalaFX 8 drag and drop node into another node

Tags: scala, javafx, drag-and-drop, scalafx

I need to drag a rectangle node into another one. ScalaFX should be based on JavaFX so this should work similarly, right? Since there is not much ScalaFX documentation, I tried to find some JavaFX examples and I have read quite a lot of them, but none of them is working for me :(

As far as I understand it, there should be 3 types of Drag and Drop operations:

- Simple Drag and Drop on single node
- **Full drag and drop** (I should use this one to interact between nodes)
- Drag and drop files and data among applications

I ended up with this simple class:

```
class GameBoardRectangle(val coordinates: Coordinates) extends Rectangle
  {
    width = 32
    height = 32
    stroke = Color.BLACK

    var dragDelta: Point2D = new Point2D(0,0)

    onMousePressed = new EventHandler[input.MouseEvent] {
      override def handle(event: input.MouseEvent): Unit = {
        dragDelta = new Point2D(layoutX.toDouble - event.getSceneX,
          layoutY.toDouble - event.getSceneY)
          //event.setDragDetect(true)
          rect.setMouseTransparent(true)
      }
    }

    onMouseDragged = new EventHandler[input.MouseEvent] {
      override def handle(event: input.MouseEvent): Unit = {
        layoutX = event.getSceneX + dragDelta.x
        layoutY = event.getSceneY + dragDelta.y
       // println("OnMouseDragged")
        rect.setMouseTransparent(true)
        event.consume()
      }
    }

    val rect = this

    onDragDetected = new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MouseEvent): Unit = {
       // var db: Dragboard = rect.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.LINK)
        var clibpoard = new ClipboardContent()
        //event.

        println("OnDragDetected")
        rect.startFullDrag()
      //  event.consume()
      }
    }

    onMouseDragEntered = new EventHandler[MouseDragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MouseDragEvent): Unit = {
        println("onMouseDragEntered")
      }
    }

    onMouseDragExited = new EventHandler[MouseDragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MouseDragEvent): Unit = {
        println("onMouseDragExited")
      }
    }

    onMouseDragOver = new EventHandler[MouseDragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MouseDragEvent): Unit = {
        println("onMouseDragExited")

      }
    }

    onMouseDragReleased = new EventHandler[MouseDragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MouseDragEvent): Unit = {
        println ("onMouseDragReleased")
      }
    }

    onDragDropped = new EventHandler[DragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: DragEvent): Unit = {
        println("OnDragDropped")
      }
    }

    onDragDone = new EventHandler[DragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: DragEvent): Unit = {
        println("OnDragDone")
      }
    }

    onDragOver = new EventHandler[DragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: DragEvent): Unit = {
        println("OnDragOver")
        //event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK)
      }
    }

    onDragEntered = new EventHandler[DragEvent] {
      override def handle(event: DragEvent): Unit = {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.LINK)
        println("OnDragEnetered")
      }
    }
  }
```

and output from console after dragging one node over another:

```
OnDragDetected
onMouseDragEntered
onMouseDragExited
```

There is no OnDragOver method being fired.

What am I missing? I'm quite confused about amount of Drag and Drop events.